# Check if an value already exists in SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to code an account system, the accounts are stored inside an SQLite database. Whenever someone wants to create an account I first want to check if there is already an account that uses the same email(the email is not the primary key but simple text).

```
public boolean checkemail(String email)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String Query = "Select * from " + TABLE_KANIDAT + " where " + KEY_KEMAIL + " = " + "'"+email+"'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0)
    {
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: `select exists (select * from TABLE_KANIDAT where KEY_KEMAIL = 'theemail' limit 1);` returns 1 if a row exists else 0.  You need to paramaterize your statement also.

Comment: And what is the problem with this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create a method

```
public boolean checkAlreadyExist(String email)
    {
        String query = SELECT + YOUR_EMAIL_COLUMN + FROM + TABLE_NAME + WHERE + YOUR_EMAIL_COLUMN + " =?";
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{email});
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

         public boolean rowIdExists(String StrId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select id from " + TABLE_USERRATE
            + " where id=?", new String[]{StrId});
    boolean exists = (cursor.getCount() > 0);
    /*cursor.close();
    db.close();*/
    return exists;
}


    if (rowIdExists("ValuesId")) {
            //do something
            } else {
              //do something  
            }
```